# Colour map for 3D scatter plots in matplotlib not being applied properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have a set of data, with coordinates that I extract to form the x, y, and z components of my point. In that same dataframe, I have an intensity (let's call it `j`) that I would like to use to map the colour map on to the point. My script to add points over iteration from my Pandas dataframe:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for row, index in df.iterrows():
    x = df[row]['x']
    y = df[row]['y']
    z = df[row]['z']
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, cmap='bwr', c=df[row]['j'])

plt.show()
```

However, all the points are a singular colour and don't respond to having different colour shades per point, as defined by `df[row]['j']` (which returns an integer corresponding to the intensity of my point). Am I missing something obvious or is the for loop making the colour mapping not possible (i.e. it is setting a baseline for the colour every iteration and thus not able to distinguish a min/max since each new point creates a new min/max)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], cmap='bwr', c=df['j'])
```

(without any for loop)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the map like this:
[image]

My code is directly use the `df.column` you want to plot:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
t="""
0 , 1 , 0 , b
2 , 1 , 2 , b
3 , 2 , 1 , r
2 , 3 , 5 , r
3 , 2 , 5 , b
7 , 3 , 6 , g
8 , 3 , 6 , g
2 , 3 , 6 , g
7 , 3 , 6 , g
8 , 3 , 6 , g
2 , 3 , 6 , g
2 , 3 , 6 , g
3 , 4 , 6 , g
5 , 2 , 6 , r
6 , 2 , 6 , r
7 , 3 , 6 , r
2 , 1 , 6 , g
7 , 13 , 6 , r
8 , 23 , 6 , r
2 , 33 , 6 , r
"""

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),names=['x','y','z','j'],sep=',')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z,c=df.y)

plt.show()
```

Hope help you.